# Knockout calculate container height from custom element after rendering items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am writing a custom binding that amongst other things, needs to know what height it is before running some display logic. The contents are rendered in a `foreach` binding.

Normally, KO would call my binding `init` before any of these items are rendered, thus meaning the height is incorrect.

I then used `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` and manually bound the child items before using the height; this works fine in the `init`.

The problem is, I'd like to have the binding fire an `update` and recalculate height when the items are updated, and the above pattern gives me `You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element` if I change `init` to `update`, understandably enough.

Here is cut down code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: rerun">Re-run</a>
<hr/>
<div class="container" data-bind="test: true">
    <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
        <div class="item" data-bind="text: ID"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<hr/>
<b id="res"></b>
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    clear: both;
}

.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

CODE:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: 
        function(el, f_valueaccessor, allbindings, viewmodel, bindingcontext) 
        {
            var val = ko.unwrap(f_valueaccessor());

            if(!!val)
            {   
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingcontext, el);

                $('#res').html($(el).height());

                return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
            }
        }
};

function Model(data, mapping)
{
    var _this = this;
    var _mapping = $.extend({}, {}, mapping);

    this.Items = ko.observableArray();        

    if(data)
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, _mapping, _this);

    this.rerun = function(model, e)
    {
        _this.Items(_this.genItems());
    }

    this.genItems = function()
    {        
        var a = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < 10 + (Math.random() * 20); i++)
            a.push({ID:i});

        return a;
    }

    this.rerun();
}

var model = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

And a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/tzrxbojj/

I can see two ways to solve this:

1. Pass an object to the binding that contains a function reference that can be called by the model when the items are changed to force a recalculate (this works fine but is pretty clunky)
2. Use an `afterRender` on the `foreach` (this works fine also, but adds code to the model)

The `afterRender` solution works fine and may well turn out to be the recommended method; however it does mean that I have to add this to any model that needs similar functionality, and the custom binding seems like a really nice abstraction.

Is there a good (i.e. better than #1) way of getting this to work simply using the single custom binding on the container?

Comment: Just curious: in the fiddle you linked to, the code works fine without `$('#res').html($(el).height());` and the container re-adapts.. Is your rl implementation more complex, so that it cannot be solved merely with CSS?

Comment: Yes; the calculations are done by a plugin that does various other things with those values as well as just setting the container height. Think of it not as simply setting the height so much as calling an opaque function when that height is available.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing missing in your solution is that the custom binding needs to know about the items model in order to subscribe to its changes and recalculate the height of the element. I also made the height an observable for the solution to be more like Knockout is intended to be used.

My solution also does not require `controlsDescendantBindings: true`.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: rerun">Re-run</a>
<hr/>
<div class="container" data-bind="test: {heightValue: containerHeight, itemsModel: Items}">
    <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
        <div class="item" data-bind="text: ID"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<hr/>
<b id="res" data-bind="text: containerHeight"></b>
```

Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: 
        function(el, f_valueaccessor, allbindings, viewmodel, bindingcontext) 
        {
            var data = f_valueaccessor();
            var recalculate = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    data.heightValue($(el).height());
                }, 0);
            }
            data.itemsModel.subscribe(function () {
                recalculate();
            });

            recalculate();
        }
};
```

The setTimeout with zero helps to fire the height recalculation after the rendering is complete.

And the view model is mostly the same with the exception of added observable for the container height:

```
this.containerHeight = ko.observable();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6rawhrL/)